# Android Receiving Messages From WebSocket Server

Tags: javascript, android, websocket, okhttp, stomp

I am working on an Android application where I need to connect to a web socket and receive messages to unlock the app from the web server. Receiving messages have been implemented through Stompclient on java script but i need to do the same on Android. I read about Okhttp3 and its support for web socket so I was able to implement it The websocket is opening but I don't know how to subscribe to receive the messages on Android.

```
Here is the Java Script Code:

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat WebSocket</title>
        <script src="/gravity/resources/sockjs-0.3.4.js"></script>
        <script src="/gravity/resources/stomp.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var stompClient = null;

            function setConnected(connected) {
                document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
                document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
                document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility 
                  = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
            }

            function connect() {
                var socket = new SockJS('/gravity/api/gravitywebsocket');
                stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);  
                stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                    setConnected(true);
                    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);                 
                    stompClient.subscribe('/pos/asycnronous', function(messageOutput) {
                        var body = messageOutput.body; body.a=5;
                        showMessageOutput(body);
                                                                                                     });
                });                
            }

            function disconnect() {
                if(stompClient != null) {
                    stompClient.disconnect();
                }
                setConnected(false);
                console.log("Disconnected");
            }

            function sendMessage() {
                var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
                var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
                stompClient.send("/api/poschannel", {},JSON.stringify({'from':from, 'text':text}));
                                   }

            function showMessageOutput(messageOutput) {
                var response = document.getElementById('response');
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
                p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(messageOutput.a + "***" +messageOutput.from + ": " 
                  + messageOutput.text + " (" + messageOutput.time + ")"));
                response.appendChild(p);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="disconnect()">
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Choose a nickname"/>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
                <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">
                    Disconnect
                </button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div id="conversationDiv">
                <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Write a message..."/>
                <button id="sendMessage" onclick="sendMessage();">Send</button>
                <p id="response"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**My Android Implementation:**

```
public class ServerConnection {
    public enum ConnectionStatus {
        DISCONNECTED,
        CONNECTED
    }

    public interface ServerListener {
        void onNewMessage(String message);

        void onStatusChange(ConnectionStatus status);
    }

    private WebSocket mWebSocket;
    private OkHttpClient mClient;
    private String mServerUrl;
    private Handler mMessageHandler;
    private Handler mStatusHandler;
    private ServerListener mListener;

    public class SocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            super.onOpen(webSocket, response);

            try {
                System.out.println("On Open: Observe Response: " + response.body().string());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Utility.stringify(e);
            }

            Message message = mMessageHandler.obtainMessage(Contract.ACTIVATE_POS_MESSAGE, ConnectionStatus.CONNECTED);
            mStatusHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
            System.out.println("OnMessage: Observe result: " + text);
            Message message = mMessageHandler.obtainMessage(Contract.ACTIVATE_POS_MESSAGE, text);
            mMessageHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
            super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes.toString());
            System.out.println("OnMessage: Observe result: " + bytes.toString());
            Message message = mMessageHandler.obtainMessage(Contract.ACTIVATE_POS_MESSAGE, bytes.toString());
            mMessageHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
            super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
            System.out.println("OnClosed: Observe Reason: " + reason);
            Message message = mMessageHandler.obtainMessage(Contract.ACTIVATE_POS_MESSAGE, ConnectionStatus.DISCONNECTED);
            mMessageHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
            super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
            System.out.println("OnFailure: Observe Response: " + response);
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    public ServerConnection(String url) {
        mClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .build();

        mServerUrl = url;
    }

    public void connect(ServerListener listener) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(mServerUrl)
                .build();
        mWebSocket = mClient.newWebSocket(request, new SocketListener());
        mWebSocket.send("Hello, Testing Connection!");
        mListener = listener;
        mMessageHandler = new Handler(msg -> {
            mListener.onNewMessage((String) msg.obj);
            return true;
        });
        mStatusHandler = new Handler(msg -> {
            mListener.onStatusChange((ConnectionStatus) msg.obj);
            return true;
        });
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        mWebSocket.close(1000, "Completed");
        mListener = null;
        mMessageHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        mStatusHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        mWebSocket.send(message);
    }
}
```

**The LockScreenActivity that needs to receive unlock message from server:**

```
public class LockScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ServerConnection.ServerListener{
    private ServerConnection mServerConnection;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);
        mServerConnection = new ServerConnection(TerminalDetails.WEB_SOCKET_URL);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

       Timer timer = new Timer();
       timer.schedule(timerTask, 10000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mServerConnection.connect(this);
        mServerConnection.sendMessage("Hello, Testing Connection!");
        Utility.showToast(this, "Connected to the Web Socket");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewMessage(String message) {
        try {
            Utility.showToast(this, "A new message received!");
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Utility.stringify(e);
        }
        validateResponse(jsonObject);
    }
```

I will answer more questions about the code if needed. Thanks